# Ancient math: a pill on the ground

Tags: riddle, knowledge

> There are 3 floors of a building.
>
> There are 3 sets of 4 people going to every floor one-by-one.
>
> There is a "pill" on the ground, which means nothing.
>
> What does this mean?

Hint 1:

> Start with the third statement then you can go to 1 and 2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe this is supposed to be

> Mayan numerals.
>  [image: image of Mayan numerals from 0 to 19]
>  The "pill" is the turtle shell representing 0; the three "floors" are the lines representing fives, and the "people" are the dots on top representing 1 to 4.